# query returning zero results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a SQL query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))

FROM Mytable

WHERE  TableID = '101'
```

The above query runs fine.

I want to have results for email addresses, for which TableID has different values like 123,421.

So, when I write the following query, why do I get 0 result returned in MySQLWorkbencch?

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))

    FROM Mytable

    WHERE  TableID = '101'
    AND    TableId = '123'
    AND    TableID = '421'
```

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: you are requiring a match of all those table ids at the same time with your AND statement

Comment: Use OR AND defines when all are true while OR opts for either

Answer (score 5):

Use `OR` instead of `AND`. Using `AND`, you're requiring a column value to be equal to 3 different constant values. This violates the laws of the universe.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
FROM Mytable
WHERE TableID = '101' OR TableId = '123' OR TableID = '421';
```

Alternatively, you can use the `IN` clause. In terms of actual execution they're equivalent, but in some cases `IN` might be easier to read, especially if the list gets longer:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
FROM Mytable
WHERE TableID IN ('101', '123', '421');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use IN Clause instead.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
FROM Mytable
WHERE  TableID IN  ('101','123','421')
```

Answer (score 2):

USE **IN** or **OR**

1. By using **OR**:

   ```
   SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
   FROM Mytable
   WHERE  TableID = '101'
   OR  TableId = '123'
   OR    TableID = '421'
   ```
2. By using **IN**:

   ```
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(EMAIL_ADDRESS))
   FROM MYTABLE
   WHERE TABLEID IN ('101','123','421');
   ```

**Explanation:**

- You are trying to check if a single value matches 3 different unique values, similar to checking if

'Dog is equals to Dog  `AND` Dog is equals to Cat `AND` Dog is equals to Cow'

Which returns `false`

- With Option 1, using OR, it would be like

'Dog is equals to Dog  `OR` Dog is equals to Cat `OR` Dog is equals to Cow'

Which returns `true`

- With Option 2, using IN, it would be like

'Is Dog available in list containing Dog, Cat, Cow'

Which returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

Try with either `OR` or `IN` clause. `AND` returns records when all specified condition is true which is not happen in your case that's why return 0 result or empty result.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
    FROM Mytable
    WHERE  TableID = '101'
    OR    TableId = '123'
    OR    TableID = '421';
```

OR

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(email_address))
FROM Mytable
WHERE  TableID IN('101','123','421');
```